# Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring

I am facing problems when i run my project on eclipse on apache tomcat server as i am spring as a framework, I added the necessary jars The error is:
Could please any one let me know what could be the issue ?

```
  May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
  INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/../jre/lib/i386;D:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\eclipse;;.
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:my-app' did not find a matching property.
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8181
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 609 ms
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\WorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\my-app\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1015)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 13, 2017 1:10:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/my-app] startup failed due to previous errors
May 13, 2017 1:10:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8181
May 13, 2017 1:10:44 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
May 13, 2017 1:10:44 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/21  config=null
May 13, 2017 1:10:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 479 ms
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>my-app</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- declaring base package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Controller" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/message" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginDao" class="com.DaoImpl.LoginDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="loginService" class="com.serviceImpl.LoginServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="loginVal" class="com.Bean.LoginValidation" />

    <bean id="signUpDao" class="com.DaoImpl.SignUpDaoImpl " />
    <bean id="signUpService" class="com.serviceImpl.SignUpServiceImpl " />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE" />
        <property name="username" value="hr" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: The ContextLoaderListener is used to integrate Spring with other web application. see here, https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/

Comment: without more information about your code and configuration it's hard to help you. Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i edit my post to add web.xml and spring-servlet.xml..now could you please help..?